# Why must replaceChild() be used to replace a DOM element? Why is nodeChild[#] = element not adequate?

Tags: javascript, dom

As the title says, I have some code here that works:

```
const oaxaca = document.getElementById('oaxaca');
const textNode = document.createTextNode('sample');
oaxaca.replaceChild(textNode, oaxaca.childNodes[0]); // This works
```

Yet this does not:

```
const oaxaca = document.getElementById('oaxaca');
const textNode = document.createTextNode('sample');
oaxaca.childNodes[0] = textNode; // Does nothing
```

Could someone explain why this doesn't work, it seems intuitive that it would have the same effect but it does not alter childNodes[0] at all.

Comment: I'd say because the DOM is build with OOP where actions are modelled as methods. But there are exceptions of course…

Comment: Hey Bergi, quick one. On the NodeList object it says it is 'read-only', does this mean the NodeList itself cannot be reassigned or does it mean its elements within the nodelist cannot be reassigned, or both? Thanks, I was thinking it could be something to do with that

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: Because replaceChild [does much more than just assign](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-replace), there are a bunch of other administrative tasks that (need to) happen.

Comment: @MyssaMyssa Where does it say readonly "*on the NodeList object*"? All I see is that `node.childNodes` is documented as read-only, which means you cannot reassign a different nodelist to that property.